# Paste Excel Chart/Range as Enhanced Metafile into email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How can I paste a range of cells and a chart as enhanced metafiles in an email?

I have this code:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .Display
End With
Signature = OutMail.HTMLBody

With OutMail
    .To = "me@gmail.com"
    .CC = "me@school.edu"
    .Subject = Date & " is Today's date"
    .HTMLBody = emailBody & vbNewLine & RangetoHTML(Range("V9:AX89")) & "Chart 1" & RangetoHTML(Range("V126:AA202")) & chart3 & RangetoHTML(Range("V210:AX222")) & vbNewLine & "This message was automated. Please respond if something is wrong with it. Thanks!"
    .Display
End With
```

This pastes the ranges as "excel-style" text.

How can I change this code such that the ranges are enhanced metafiles?

Also, where my code says `"Chart 1"` and `"Chart 2"`, I want to paste the charts named "Chart 1" and "Chart 2" as enhanced metafiles.

NOTES: emailBody is a string of text, and rangeToHTML is a function I borrowed (The author of the RangeToHTML code section is Ron De Bruin. You can learn more about him here: rondebruin.nl).

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```